# How do I validate empty array select box in laravel?

Tags: html, laravel, select

I am using laravel to develop an app that require an array of select option

My code

```
   <select name="test_id[]" class="form-control select-test-{{$idselect}}"
     id="select-{{Illuminate\Support\Str::random(10)}}">
     <option value="">Select Patient Test</option>
     @foreach ($tests as $item)
         <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
     @endforeach
   </select>
```

Laravel validation code

```
 $request->validate([
        'test_id' => 'required:array'
    ], [
       
        'test_id.required' => "Test is required"
    ]);
```

it goes through even when no selected

Output when not selected

[image]

Comment: shouldnt the rule be `required|array`? I dont believe `required` has any parameters (which you pass by using `:`)

Comment: @Flame I changed it but it did not work for me.

Comment: So what is your requirement? A user below suggested `multiple` but do you even need that? Do you even know what it does? What is your input supposed to post? You probably just need to use `'test_id' => 'required|integer'`. This validation is really simple if you read the Laravel docs. It sounds like you're simply testing A/B stuff without knowing what you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

Well the only thing you are missing is the `multiple` attribute in your select element.

```
<select multiple name="test_id[]" class="form-control select-test-{{$idselect}}" id="select-{{Illuminate\Support\Str::random(10)}}">
```

Comment: I added the multiple but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

values are integer I guess, so you have to set validation for each index using * like this:

```
    'test_id.*' : 'required|integer'
```

**p.s: Asterisk symbol (*) is used to check values in the array, not the array itself.**